# Cournot Price Competition setup

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, game-theory, economics

**NOTE: This is a variation of the question I previously asked here, [Economic price optimisation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268658).**

The problem is the same as the previous linked question, however I am now looking to find the prices set by the Firms if they undergo *Cournot* competition. The profit functions for Firm 1 and Firm 2 are, respectively:

$$\Pi_1(p_1,p_2)=\frac{25p_1}{(p_1-0.6p_2)^{1.1}}-0.0815[\frac{25}{(p_1-0.6p_2)^{1.1}}]^{1.9}$$
$$\Pi_2(p_1,p_2)=\frac{25p_2}{(p_2-0.6p_1)^{1.1}}-0.0645[\frac{25}{(p_2-0.6p_1)^{1.1}}]^{1.9}$$

In this case, the Firms now set their prices simultaneously, and I am looking to find the prices the Firms set in equilibrium.

I am just looking for some help in how I go about this question. I understand that I need to find optimal prices $p_1^*$, $p_2^*$ by maximising both profit functions.

$$max_{p_1}\Pi_1(p_1,p_2)$$
$$max_{p_2}\Pi_2(p_1,p_2)$$

This again has to be solved using a numerical method which I will be programming within MATLAB, just as I did with a previous question which can be seen here, [Stackelberg Competition Matlab Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281070). The numerical methods will find the maximum price in each case for the inputted price from the other firm. For instance, I can easily find $max_{p_1}\Pi_1(p_1,p_2)$ for each inputted value of $p_2$, and vice versa with the other maximisation problem.

I am then unsure how to pursue with this question. How do I go about finding the prices they both set in equilibrium in order to maximise their profits? I would also like to analyse the robustness of the profit functions, how they react to changes in parameters so any advice on that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Price competition is not usually associated with Cournot competition. Please check your wording and consider changing the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_i(p_j)$ be the *best response* of firm $i$ to firm $j$'s strategy of choosing its price to be $p_j$, that is, for $i\ne j\in \{1,2\}$,
$$
B_i(p_j) = \arg\max_{p_i} \Pi_i\left(p_1,p_2\right).
$$
The Nash equilibrium $(p_1^*,p_2^*)$ obtains as the solution to the system of equations
\begin{eqnarray}
p_1^*&=&B_1(p_2^*)\\
p_2^*&=&B_2(p_1^*).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So in a Cournot price competition, in equilibrium, both firms will set the same price? But then obviously their outputs will be different? Is that correct?

Comment: @al_sweets:  You asked, "How do I go about finding the prices they both set in equilibrium in order to maximise their profits?" My response was intended to provide a simple, game-theoretic approach to solving the joint pricing problem.  However, I think there are other issues with your problem as stated.  Cournot competition typically refers to an environment in which firms choose _quantities_ and price is determined by meeting subsequent supply with demand.  Can you clarify whether you meant _Bertrand_ competition, or perhaps have a non-standard variety of Cournot competition in mind?

Comment: I am actually unsure of the competition. I just know that the Firms want to maximise their profits, they set their prices simultaneously, and I need to find the prices they set in equilibrium. So is your setup correct for that?